# Why am I the only one who can connect to my Minecraft server?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, minecraft

I'm local-hosting a Minecraft Java Edition server on Lubuntu 20.04, and only people on the LAN can join it. I've set up a port forward for the PC with port 25565, disabled the entire firewall, but nothing works. I tried canyouseeme.org, and port 25565 is open, so I figure it's something with Lubuntu. I set up the iptables rules following this github file: https://gist.github.com/Maxopoly/6c925a1f18f9e2f3b9818d1c1582b17e, I've also re-enabled the firewall with this option: `sudo ufw allow 25565` and restarted the PC, still nothing. Are there more settings I have to configure?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question except to provide a complete guide to host this service, but that is way too broad for Ask Ubuntu.  Please do more research about your problem and provide more specific context and details so that there is an answerable question.

Comment: Port forwarding only works if you have a public IP. If you are behind a carrier-grade NAT then port forwarding is like opening a door that stands directly before a solid wall.

Comment: @user535733 I went onto Xfinity Xfi and created the port forward on the device, set the port to 25565. I'm sure I did nothing wrong.

Comment: That information need to be in your Question above, not buried in a comment. Comments are intended to help you improve your question; to make it answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1360096/edit) and add all new the information in your question.  The comments are our channel to ask for clarifications. You may add a comment alerting commentator when you update the question.

Comment: Check that your router is not behind a carrier-grade NAT: Try to ping your router from both the LAN and the WAN.

Comment: @user535733 How would I do that?

Comment: You use the `ping` command.